# mongoDB update statement using regex

Tags: regex, mongodb

I have the following in mongoDB:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("552f4bf5344fbaee0f62ccef"),
    "name" : "testcase2",
    "steps" : [
        {
            "spec1" : "postPet"
        },
        {
            "spec2" : "putPet"
        },
        {
            "spec2" : "getPetsHistory"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to pull an element out of the steps array. I can only use the following values: "testcase2", "postPet".

I used regex in the update query as discussed in the following link: https://gist.github.com/gatesvp/1021164

My query is:

```
db.testcaseCollection.update({"name" : "testcase3"}, {$pull : {"steps" :      {$regex: 'postPet'}}})
```

and the result was:

```
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })
```

Can anyone help with what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "pulling" an element out?

Comment: remove the element from the json array

Comment: Your update query is matching on `testcase3` and not `testcase2`. Probably you don't have any element which is matching the regex `postPet`.

Comment: sorry that was a typo here. I had actually used testcase2 itself

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pull a string from an array based on the regex. The problem is that your array consists of maps/objects/whatever, so not surprisingly you can not pull anything. This is why you see 1 `matched` and 0 `modifies`.

```
db.testcaseCollection.update({
  "name" : "testcase2"
}, {
   $pull : {
      steps: { spec1: {$regex: 'postPet' }}
   }
})
```

Take a look at documentation as to how you can use [$pull](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#remove-items-from-an-array-of-documents)